# PowerShell script to go through a directory of csvs and convert them to html

Tags: csv, powershell, for-loop, foreach

This is a PowerShell question, not a SharePoint question.

I'm using a script to grab an inventory of SharePoint features, web parts, etc.  It outputs each type of report in the same directory as csv files.  So I'll end up with a directory on my computer with the csv files.

[image]

I'd like to run another PowerShell script after the first one that converts these csvs into html files for easily readable reports.

I'm getting stuck on the part where I would import-csv each file and create each html file with similarly named html files.

[image]

Here's what I have so far.  Can anyone help me complete this to do what I want it to do?  To use Import-CSV, I have to specify the file name as you can see in $dir.  Is there another way?

```
$dir = "C:\Users\me\Desktop\output\TestInvSiteCollections.csv"

dir -LiteralPath $dir | % {Import-Csv $dir}
```

or use this somehow..

```
Import-Csv -LiteralPath $dir  | ConvertTo-Html | Out-File "C:\Users\me\Desktop\output\myhtmlfile.html"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\me\Desktop\output\*.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    Import-Csv $_ | ConvertTo-Html | Out-File -FilePath (Join-Path -Path $_.DirectoryName -ChildPath ($_.BaseName + '.html'));
}
```

I'm not entirely sure I find html tables easier to read than csv files. Excel's filtering and sorting is too useful.

Comment: This is where I got the script from https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Inventory-SharePoint-Farm-dc11fc28  I can't send the exact file because of the data, but it shows up in the csv file as a jumbled gaggle of text .. no columns or any formatting whatsoever.   The HTML file makes it readable.. and I was curious about knowing how to do this anyway

Comment: By the way, I was able to separate out the data in the csv files into columns by going into Excel, selecting the A column, Going to the Data tab, Text to Columns, delimited by comma

Comment: Ah, yeah.  If the last time you used Text to Columns delimited you didn't have comma selected, Excel seems to forget that commas separate fields in csvs.  It's trying to be smart and ends up merely inconsistent.

Comment: Yup.  I didn't have it selected and couldn't figure out why it wasn't putting it into columns.. but this was a fun exercise anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your code. It should split the name of the file and add the extension.

```
Import-Csv -LiteralPath $dir  | ConvertTo-Html | Out-File ($dir.Split(".")[0]+".html")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly more verbose method, but I generally prefer readable code over conciseness for maintainability:

```
#get the list of csv files
$csvFiles = Get-ChildItem $path -Filter *.csv

foreach ($file in $csvFiles)
{
    #create FileInfo object
    [System.IO.FileInfo]$fileInfo = "$path\$file"

    #Get base name of file
    $baseName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($file.Name)

    #do HTML conversion
    Import-Csv $fileInfo.FullName | ConvertTo-Html | Out-File "$htmlPath\$baseName.html" 
}
```

This is working code assuming you have $path defined somewhere and can obviously be modified to suite your needs.